# Authenticated curl not working in php

Tags: php, json, rest, ssl, curl

I am trying to create a simple PHP script that calls two different REST APIs on two different domains. Both services are HTTPS and require authentication. When I do a curl from the terminal, I get the response in JSON for both domains and everything works beautifully:

curl --user “myuser:mypassword” https://www.example.com/rest/api/2/projects

Notice that it's a GET, not a POST.

The strange thing is that when I try the exact same curl commands from my PHP script neither of them works.

This what happens:

- The first domain returns an empty JSON array with no errors. Just this: []
- The second domain returns this error in JSON:

  {"errors":[
    {
      "context":null,
      "message":"You are not permitted to access this resource",
      "exceptionName":"com.atlassian.stash.exception.AuthorisationException"
    }
  ]}

Here's what's NOT happening:

- No SSL certificate errors or warnings
- No authentication errors.

Even if put in a bad username or password, both services will act exactly the same way.

To me what's suspicious is that both domains don't authenticate my calls which makes me think there's either a problem with my code or in the php curl library.

Here's my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link3); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$encodedAuth = base64_encode($username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authentication : Basic ".$encodedAuth));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
```

I know some of it is redundant, but I wanted to try everything and nothing works. Any ideas?

My environment:

- OS X Yosemite (10.10.2)
- PHP 5.6.6 (I manually upgraded to the latest version as an attempt to make this work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current code mixes various approaches and does it in a conflicting way:

- the authentication header is named `Authorization:` and not `Authentication:`
- the `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY` tries to negotiate with the server and it shouldn't (neither does the working cURL command line)

Just use:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
# for debugging/non-prod
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Hans, I did try many different combinations of the headers above but I don 't think I ever left out the CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH. I'll try it as soon as I get back in the office on Monday, and I will mark your answer as correct if it works. I'm not very optimistic at this point but I really hope you're right :-)